# Is it redundant to add the same word in singular and plural form in the description meta tag?

Tags: seo

As far as SEO is concerned, is there a fundamentally functional difference between

`<meta name="keywords" content="cake">`

and

`<meta name="keywords" content="cakes">`

Comment: Your title states "description meta tag", but your example shows the "keywords meta tag"? Please clarify.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify the point that MrWhite is asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, using the same word in both singular and plural forms within the same meta description makes perfect sense as long as it is grammatically correct to do so.

In terms of SEO there is not right or wrong choices here. **However**, if the user query leads to a different search intent **your page rankings in SERP will be affected**.

According to John Mueller’s answer

> So just because one is singular and one is plural doesn’t mean that we
>   would show the same search results for those kinds of queries.

and then he continues

> It’s very possible that we see these as completely different elements
>   and maybe even as completely different intent from the user side.

More about Search intent and Muller's comment [here](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/singular-plural-keywords/267177/)

*Important note: Meta Keywords are not longer valid, relevant or important in the SEO world.*

Answer (score 2):

Google no longer uses meta keywords as a ranking factor whatsoever, and I doubt any other SEs do either.

However you mentioned it as being in the description meta tag while your question shows keyword meta tag.

Search engines recognize words in singular or plural, there is no difference regarding SEO between them in a descrtion aside from which logically makes sense to use.

All that being said Google may choose to show a different snippet from your website as the description in SE results and not use what you have set in the meta description.